# Why do some edits need more than one reviewer?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I recently reviewed a suggested edit to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55817/8563), and it told me that it needs additional reviews for this to go through. I have been reviewing suggested edits for some time and this is the first time I see this. Did this change recently? Is it applicable to all posts, or what are the criteria? What's the rationale for this?

Answer (score 3):

[This was changed last October](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151536/it-takes-two-to-tango/151586#151586)

[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/117903#117903) (see the October entry)

The current suggested edit algorithm for Physics.SE is:

- If the reviewer is the post author, their action is binding
- If the reviewer is a mod, his action is binding (yay)
- If the reviewers are neither mods nor original authors, then the *first* decision (approve/reject) to reach two supporters is taken into account.
- However, using the "improve"/"edit" button lets one bypass the double approval ([example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9584) -- Community♦ steps in as a reviewer here) -- though you have to make an extra change to the post to do this.

Looking at your history, you seem to have come across the "requires another approval" block in the past [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9578) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12651). You probably didn't notice the "needs another approval" banner , that's all:)

Comment: Fun fact: I've never seen this banner/message on any SE site. I just know it exists :)

Comment: Hmmm. The first I don't recognize, but the second one I do. I did review it and approve the edit, but I never saw any banner. Are there definitely banners when seen from the review queue? For the one in my question, I saw the edit suggestion while reading the post (i.e. the `edit` link had a `(1)` on it). Maybe that's the difference.